# Problem inherit procs from another Type in Nim

Tags: oop, inheritance, nim-lang

I was playing around with OOP in Nim and when I tried to implement inheritance between two Nim types in different files, I encounter the following problem, when inherit a type from a different file I could not inherit the procs associated to that type only the attributes.

In the following blocks of code, it is represented what I described.

```
# file car.nim

type
    Car* = ref object of RootObj
        brand*: string
        model*: string
        price*: float

proc getCarInfo*(self: Car): string =
    return "Brand: " & self.brand & "\nModel: " & self.model & "\nPrice: " & $self.price
```

```
# file ford.nim

import car

type
    Ford* = ref object of Car

proc newFord*(brand: string, model: string, price: float): Car =
    return Ford(
        brand: brand,
        model: model,
        price: price
    )
```

```
# file main.nim

import ford

proc main() =
   var ford = newFord("Ford", "Mustang", 50_000.00)
   echo ford.getCarInfo() # This does not work, error => (attempting to call undeclared routine: 'getCarInfo')

when isMainModule:
  main()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You need to re-export `getCarInfo` in `ford.nim`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried also `import car` in your **main.nim** file? The `getCarInfo` proc is defined in **car.nim**, and it is not re-exported in **ford.nim**, so `import ford` does not import `getCarInfo` as well.

Comment: Remember you can do `export car` in "ford.nim" to achieve that.